# IOS detail view disappearing when contains Date object and tries to update Coredata

Tags: swiftui

I trying to save a Coredata object in a SwiftUI .OnDisappear method and it conflicts with a Date() object in the View. Commenting out the Date() variable in DetailView or commenting out the code in .OnDisappear stops the view from disappearing. I made a minimum reproducible example here from the default New Project with Coredata in Xcode.

Here is a gif of the DetailView disappearing
https://imgur.com/dA2QH4D

ListView

```
struct ListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    })
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
```

DetailView

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @State var item: Item
    
    @State private var date = Date() // Comment this
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
            
            NavigationLink(destination: {
                EmptyView()
            }, label: {
                Text("History")
            })
        }
        .onDisappear {
            item.timestamp = Date() // Or Comment this
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ListView`, add a `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to your `NavigationView`, such as:

```
NavigationView { 
   //...
}.navigationViewStyle(.stack)  // <-- here
```

Comment: This is what I am using in my production app at the moment. I am trying to support an IPad version and adding this would not have a sidebar. The only workaround that I have found is removing the code in .onDisappear or the date variable which results in this simulator recording here: https://imgur.com/vaMjVnb

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationView` can only have one level of detail `NavigationLink` i.e. its `isDetail` property defaults to true. If you want more levels you have to use `.isDetail(false)` on the 2nd level and beyond.